# Trying to get all firestore documents from Angular where all mat-checkbox values are true

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

I have a number of mat-checkboxes created as below;

```
hobbies = this._formBuilder.group({
  photography: false,
  hiking: false,
//others
});
```

```
this.hobbies.valuechanges
```

Returns an object as below, with true for any checked box;

```
{
    "photography": true,
    "hiking": false,
}
```

I'm not being able to correctly create a query to a firestore database where the keys == true.

Here are some of the things i'm tried, but keep getting errors:
I guess the part i'm not being able to get past is that the keys (photography, hiking etc) are of type boolean and I need keys that are strings?

```
  Object.keys(hobbies).forEach(key => {
  if (interests[key]) {
    query.where(key, '==', true);
  }
});
```

```
interests$: Observable<string[]> = 
this.hobbies.valueChanges.pipe(
map(hobbies => Object.keys(hobbies).filter(key => 
hobbies[key]))
);
```

```
getHobbies(): Observable<any[]> {
  const hobbies = this.hobbies.value;
  const hobbiesKeys = Object.keys(hobbies);
  const hobbiesTrue = hobbiesKeys.filter(key => hobbies[key]);
  return this.firestore.collection('hobbies', ref => {
    let query: firebase.firestore.CollectionReference | firebase.firestore.Query = ref;
    hobbiesTrue.forEach(hobbies => {
      query = query.where(hobbies, '==', true);
    });
    return query;
  }).valueChanges();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you edit your question (there's a link under it) to show: 1) the code that you use to query the database, that isn't working. 2) a screenshot from the Firebase web console of a document that you expect the query to return.